# How do I get a code review link if I pushed my changes first?

Tags: git, gerrit

I committed my changes but forgot to generate a gerrit code review link and I pushed my changes to the repo.

Is there a way to generate review for the commit that I pushed?

Comment: Could you describe what you mean by "generate gerrit code review link"? Normally you don't have to *generate* anything, you just push the changes to Gerrit in `refs/for/<branch>` and the review is automatically created.

Comment: yea. for review , i forgot to push the commit to gerrit. But I pushed changes to repo.

Comment: You're using a workflow that I'm unfamiliar with. Either you'll have to explain more about what you're doing, or ask somebody at your location who knows what your workflow is.

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a code review in Gerrit post-commit.  Once data is committed to the repository it is in the repository.  If your workflow allows you to edit the central repository directly, your only option is to back out your commit and then push it to Gerrit.

Most groups using Gerrit don't allow direct pushes to prevent this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can post a code review based on the commit ids

```
`post-review --revision-range="commitId1:CommitId2"`
```